# Only first filter being checked on logger

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, logging, filter

So, right now, I have a process that spawns multiple threads, each with their own instance data. I need to inject context-specific information into each of the logging statements that are called throughout the various methods inside of the derived thread class (in this case, the context-specific info is the email of the person who triggered the thread to spawn).

Here is the filter I am currently using

```
class InjectionFilter(logging.Filter):                                                             
  def __init__(self, runner):                                                                    
    self.runner = runner                                                                       

  def filter(self, record):                                                                      
    record.email = self.runner.authorEmail                                         
    return (record.threadName == self.runner.getName())
```

"Runner" in this case is a class that is a subclass of Thread, hence the ability to call getName().

Now, for the filter, I instantiate a new filter every time a new thread is created by adding a new instance of the filter to the logging instance in the `__init__` method of the runner class.

```
class ThreadRunner(Thread):
  def __init__(self, other_info):
    ... other things set here ...
    ifilter = InjectionFilter(self)
    _log.addFilter(ifilter)
```

Where `_log` is my global logging instance for all of these threads.
And the filter adds perfectly fine!
I can call `_log.filters` and see each of the individual filters. 
That is working totally fine.

What isn't working is, when reading the logging statements only the first filter is actually being checked.

I added debug statements to the filter to check and see what was going on inside of it. `eprint` is just a helper method to print to `sys.stderr`

```
def filter(self, record):                                                                      
  record.email = self.runner.authorEmail                                          
  eprint("Record threadname is %s" % record.threadName)                                      
  eprint("Runner threadname is %s" % self.runner.getName())                                  
  eprint("Runner equals Record: %s" % (record.threadName == self.runner.getName()))
  return (record.threadName == self.runner.getName())
```

When I start the manager and spawn multiple threads, I get the same filter check every single time, always the first filter that was created.

Sample log output

```
Record threadname is Thread-52
Runner threadname is Thread-52
Runner equals Record: True
...
Record threadname is Thread-53
Runner threadname is Thread-52
Runner equals Record: False
...
Record threadname is Thread-54
Runner threadname is Thread-52
Runner equals Record: False
```

It only ever compares it to Thread-52, which is the first filter that was created. But if I print out all of the filters applied to the logger

```
for fil in _log.filters:
  print(fil.runner.getName())
```

I get

```
Thread-52
Thread-53
Thread-54
```

So I KNOW that all of the filters are being applied to the logger, but they aren't all being compared for some reason. I get `False` for the filter compare statement on every single log statement after the first thread.

Does Python only check the first filter? Am I setting something up wrong? Am I missing something here?

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward, but Python's logging documentation doesn't make the most sense to me.

If you need more context, or if I'm unclear, please let me know. I want to get this done. Haha

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, in case anyone ever gets stuck with something like this in the future (or maybe you wont because you're a better programmer than I am, haha)

For logging in Python, only one of the filters has to fail for the entire log message to be dropped. I thought it would check the filters and see if at least one of them passed, but I realize how that thought process is broken now.

So, to get around this, I instantiated a new handler for each thread that spawned, and applied a new instance of the filter to that handler, and then I applied the handler to the `_log` instance.

Now, `_log` has many handlers and each one of those handlers has a single filter. The logging statement will check through each one of the handlers and only the one with the proper filter will be sent through. :)

It works!